# Cordova iOS error, Failed to install the requested application

Tags: ios, cordova, emulation

I am making a Cordova app for iOS on MacOS. When I try to run `cordova emulate iOS` it ends up returning the following error:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
```

What's strange is it says `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` and it wasn't doing this before, and I don't think I changed anything. It's just started happening all of a sudden.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092089/cordova-builds-ios-app-and-opens-emulator-but-doesnt-install). May be it gives you some ideas to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you. The cause is that my cordova project path contains the special character ".", like /Users/somepath/path4.2.9/app

After I moved the project to a path without dot, everything works fine.