# Cordova builds iOS app and opens emulator but doesn't install

Tags: ios, cordova, emulation

I'm making an iOS app in Cordova on MacOS.

When I run `cordova emulate ios` the app builds and it opens the emulator for iPhone X iOS 11.4 but it never install the app in the emulator. It just shows the emulator home screen. It just stops there.

Why is it getting here and not going any further?

UPDATE:

Now after trying to start the emulation again a second time, it gives the following error:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
```

[image]

Comment: For iOS, you're generally going to have a better experience if you just do a `cordova build ios`.  Open the xcode proj file that it creates and run everything through xcode.  You can run the emulator from there and I never have any issues.

Comment: I'm starting to find this is a better way of working with the project. Cordova seems to muck everything up when it runs into a problem and after that even a `cordova prepare` won't finish without throwing fatal errors. But if I open the project in the projects folder using Xcode, it throws warnings but none of them are critical enough to stop the build process before emulation. Seems better.

Comment: I get same error. Xcode solution requires running cordova server which doesn't let me test ionic pro live deploy

Comment: @BShaps because first time we need select profile and after that from cli work

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I have resolved by building the app with cordova. then get myapp.app and run it over the emulator. you can follow the below steps:

## run iOS simulator

1. install Xcode
2. Open emulator
3. build the app after adding platform iOS
4. run the app with the emulator

## install ios sims

`npm install -g ios-sim@next`

## List available simulators

`xcrun simctl list`

## https://www.anexinet.com/blog/install-app-ios-simulator/

`xcrun simctl install XXXXXXX-YYYYYY-XXXX-ZZZZ-XXXXXXXXX ~/path_to_app/myapp.app`

More info
https://github.com/aymansalama/cordova-build-macos